# SQL - Select Closest Preceding Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that contains one or more entries for each patient. These contain free text and additional information about a test request. Querying on a patient would for example return:-

```
TestID      PatientID   RequestMade             FreeText
1           23           13/12/2015 11:00:00    Feeling breathless
1125        23           07/04/2016 09:31:15    Unexplained fractures
2556        23           04/12/2016 16:20:21    Check liver function – on statins
```

When viewing test results I have to pull up the request information relating to the test which will be the last one prior to the test. The results have a TestDate so a TestDate of '13/04/2016 14:21:30' should display the request of '07/04/2016 09:31:15'. I am unsure how to code this efficiently as returning every entry for a patient and doing a date comparison on each one seems not the best way to tackle it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your current query.

Comment: Store dates using a date data type, and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
 Then get back to us.

Comment: You're not thinking in **SET** operations yet. I strongly advise you to make that paradigm shift. SQL is a declarative language. (1) Your query describes what data you want. (2) The RDBMS retrieves the data. (3) If you have the right indexes, it will be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *one* test before another test for a single patient *and* the test you are looking for only appears once, then you can do this with a single query as:

```
select t.*
from tests t
where t.patientid = 23 and
      t.requestmade < (select t2.requestmade
                       from tests t2
                       where t2.patientid = t.patientid and
                             t2.testid = ?
                      )
order by t.requestmade desc
limit 1;
```